# Python - sobre asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, corotina, pynput

Comecei a testar `pynput` com `asyncio`, mas tem um problema que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. Meu código:

```
current = set()


def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        current.add(key)
        print('Y')
    if key == keyboard.Key.down:
        print('Z')


async def listener():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_release=None, on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(listener())

print('x')
```

Bom, pelo que eu entendi, mesmo o que vem depois de `loop.run_until_complete(função)"`não depende do fim do loop, então o `print('x')` deveria ser executado junto com o loop, é isso?

No meu exemplo, nada escrito após o loop é executado até ele acabar, o que eu acho é que o meu problema está aqui:

```
async def listener():
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=None, on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Mas ainda assim eu não sei como resolver.

Comment: Tem certeza que a biblioteca `pynput` utiliza corotinas? Pelo o que li rapidamente na documentação, utiliza *thread*.

Comment: Meu deus, eu estava tão focado pensando que o meu problema era com o asyncio que não parei pra pensar no pynput, obrigado pela ajuda.